# How to update multiple values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

First off, I'm sorry for my poor English.

I'm making information system for school and have a problem when I update data for student. There are siblings fields on student form. They can add one or more siblings (one to many relationship). The program has been successfully to adding siblings into databases (there are two databases, student (id [auto increment - primary key], student_id name, sex, age, ..., etc) and siblings (id (primary key), student_id, siblings_name, siblings_age, ..., etc).

But, the program has been failed when I update siblings data.

ADD SIBLINGS
php:

```
<table id='siblingsTable'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='addRow()'><img src='../images/add.png'/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteRow()'><img src='../images/delete.png'/></a><br />
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th></th>
</table>
```

js:

```
<script>
   function addRow() {
   var table = document.getElementById("siblingsTable");
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var element1 = document.createElement("input");
   element1.type = "text";
   element1.name    = "siblings_name[]";
   element1.value   = "";
   cell1.appendChild(element1);

   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var element2 = document.createElement("input");
   element2.type = "text";
   element2.name = "siblings_age[]";
   element2.value = "";
   cell2.appendChild(element2);
}

function deleteRow() {
   var table = document.getElementById("siblingsTable");
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}
</script>
```

saving to database:

```
if (!empty($_POST['siblings_name']) && !empty($_POST['siblings_age']) && is_array($_POST['siblings_name']) && is_array($_POST['siblings_age']) && count($_POST['siblings_name']) === count($_POST['siblings_age'])) {
    $auth_array = $_POST['auth_key'];
    $name_array = $_POST['siblings_name'];
    $age_array = $_POST['siblings_age'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {
            $auth = mysql_real_escape_string($auth_array);
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name_array[$i]);
            $age = mysql_real_escape_string($age_array[$i]);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO skkk_web_siblings (auth_key, siblings_name, siblings_age) VALUES ('$auth', '$name', '$age')");
        }
    }
```

[image: Table "Add Siblings"]

**This is my problem when i want to updating data:**

```
$sib = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(auth_key) FROM skkk_web_siblings WHERE auth_key = '$_GET[id]'");
$totalsiblings = mysql_result($sib,0);
...
$siblings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skkk_web_siblings WHERE auth_key = '$_GET[id]'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($siblings)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['siblings_name'];
                $age = $row['siblings_age'];
                $siblingsname[] = $name;
                $siblingsage[] = $age;
            }
...
...
...
<table id='siblingsTable'>
                    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='editRow()'><img src='../images/edit.png'/></a><br />
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
</table>
...
<script>
    function editRow() {
        var table       = document.getElementById("siblingsTable");

        var total   = '<?php echo $totalsiblings; ?>';
        var name    = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($siblingsname); ?>');
        var age = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($siblingsage); ?>');
        var i;
        var table = '';
        for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            tbl += '<input type="text" name="siblings_name[]" value="' + name[i] + '"/>';
            tbl += '<input type="text" name="siblings_age[]" value="' + age[i] + '"/>';
        }
        document.getElementById("siblingsTable").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
...
//updating to database
if (!empty($_POST['siblings_name']) && !empty($_POST['siblings_age']) && is_array($_POST['siblings_name']) && is_array($_POST['siblings_age']) && count($_POST['siblings_name']) === count($_POST['siblings_age'])) {
            $name_array = $_POST['siblings_name'];
            $age_array = $_POST['siblings_age'];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {
                $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name_array[$i]);
                $age = mysql_real_escape_string($age_array[$i]);
                mysql_query("UPDATE skkk_web_siblings SET siblings_name = '$name', siblings_age = '$age' WHERE auth_key = '$_POST[id]'");
            }
        }
```

When I update one name, it changes all siblings name. What should I do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should utilize the `sibling.id`, and use that in your `UPDATE` instead of the `auth_key`, since `auth_key` is not unique so it will update multiple rows. You could use the `sibling.id` as the array key, ie. `name="siblings_name[{$id}]"`, which could then be used in the `UPDATE` query.